# Validate a form using a provider ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-context

I'm making an auth system, and I have an issue on validate the input...

I have a provider that have login,register and sigout functions that talk to firebase..
Here the login function inside the provider.js

```
    login(email,password){
        try{
            app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) //effettuo il login, se va tutto bene... then =>
            .then(() =>{
                var user = app.auth().currentUser; //prendo l'utente corrente
                user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => { //prendo l'id_token dell'utente corrente
                    this.setState({ //aggiorno lo stato
                        isAuth : true,
                        currentUser: user,
                        currentUserToken: idToken,
                        userPassword: password
                    })
                    console.log("Login: id_token corrente: ",this.state.currentUserToken)
                    localStorage.setItem('password', password)
                })

                localStorage.setItem('userLogged', JSON.stringify(user)) //aggiorno il localstorage con l'utente corrente
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if(error.code === 'auth/wrong-password' || error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                    console.error("Errore nell'authenticazione: ", error.code)

                 }
            })

        }catch(e){
            alert(e)
        }
}
```

Then I have a component called LoginModal, that access to login function using CONTEXT API

```
<AuthConsumer>
{({login}) => (
    <Modal open={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <ModalHeader>Accedi</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
    <Form>
        <FormGroup>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <FormInput placeholder = "mariorossi@splitlabs.it" id="email" value = {this.state.LogEmail} onChange = {(e) => this.setState({logEmail: e.target.value})}/>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <FormInput placeholder = "******" type = "password" id="password" value = {this.state.LogPassword} onChange = {(e) => this.setState({logPassword: e.target.value})}/>
        </FormGroup>
    </Form>
    <Button onClick ={() => {
        login(this.state.logEmail, this.state.logPassword)


    }} outline>Accedi</Button>
    </ModalBody>
 )}
</AuthConsumer>
```

**My question is, How do I get the error occurred in the login provider and display the error on the login modal???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set the error that you get from Firebase into the state, and then use that in your rendering.

So

```
try{
    app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    ...
    .catch(error => {
        if(error.code === 'auth/wrong-password' || error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
            console.error("Errore nell'authenticazione: ", error.code)
        }
        this.setState({ signinError: error });
    })
```

And then:

```
<AuthConsumer>
{({login}) => (
    <Modal open={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <ModalHeader>Accedi</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
    (this.state.signinError ? <div>{this.state.signinError}</div? : "")
    <Form>
        <FormGroup>
```

There might be some syntax errors in that last snippet, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I can not upvote you answer because I'm lvl 11, but I will checkmark it for sure!